# How to Stop Draggable After Drop in Droppable in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/YvJhE/901/) and let me know how I can Stop Dragging After Dropping in Droppable?

Here is the code I have

```
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({cancel:false});
    $( "#droppable-1" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
             $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      }
    });
        $( "#droppable-2" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
             $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      }
    });
        $( "#droppable-3" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
             $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      }
    });
  });
```

and here is the HTML

```
<button type="button" id="App-1" class="btn btn-default btn-xs draggable">App-1</button>
<button type="button" id="App-2" class="btn btn-default btn-xs draggable">App-2</button>
<button type="button" id="App-3" class="btn btn-default btn-xs draggable">App-3</button>

<div id="droppable-1" class="droppable ui-widget-header"></div>
<div id="droppable-2" class="droppable ui-widget-header"></div>
<div id="droppable-3" class="droppable ui-widget-header"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the disable method like in:

```
$( "#droppable-1" ).droppable({
   drop: function( event, ui ) {
      $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight").disable();
   }
});
```

```js
$(function () {
  $( ".draggable" ).draggable({cancel:false});
  $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      $(this).addClass( "ui-state-highlight").disable();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.droppable{
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="App-1" class="btn btn-default btn-xs draggable">App-1</button>
<button type="button" id="App-2" class="btn btn-default btn-xs draggable">App-2</button>
<button type="button" id="App-3" class="btn btn-default btn-xs draggable">App-3</button>

<div id="droppable-1" class="droppable ui-widget-header"></div>
<div id="droppable-2" class="droppable ui-widget-header"></div>
<div id="droppable-3" class="droppable ui-widget-header"></div>
```